# now vs. any more

Tags: grammar

Is there a difference between "It doesn't matter now" and "It doesn't matter anymore" when they are used in the sense of "from now on"?

On the other hand, I often see that **now** is preferred in affirmative sentences whereas **anymore** is used in negative sentences. Is it okay to use **now** in any negative sentence?

Thank you in advance for your answers ;)

Comment: English is flexible here - both are grammatical with negative sentences.

Comment: Meaning is different. "Now" means at present without saying anything about the future, while "anymore" means at present and in the future. But both are grammatical.

Comment: Thanks, mate. That was really helpful.